# react proxy causing issue with response getting an HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a react project with a .Net backend, to avoid CORS issues, I am using a proxy on the react project and is works great when I test it in local host.

When I deploy the website on the server I get a 200 however I get an HTML response instead of the Json with my data

the HTML look like this and thus resp.Json() fail with `Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON`

Any idea what's causing this issue?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
      <script defer="defer" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>CRM</title>
      <link href="/static/css/main.f4f2875d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <style>body,html{background-attachment:fixed;background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat}.ONLINE{color:green}.OFFLINE{color:red}</style>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
      <script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,f,i=r[0],l=r[1],a=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<i.length;c++)f=i[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,f)&&o[f]&&s.push(o[f][0]),o[f]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,i=1;i<t.length;i++){var l=t[i];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function f(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,f),t.l=!0,t.exports}f.m=e,f.c=n,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=f(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)f.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var i=this.webpackJsonpundefined=this.webpackJsonpundefined||[],l=i.push.bind(i);i.push=r,i=i.slice();for(var a=0;a<i.length;a++)r(i[a]);var p=l;t()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.76019c9a.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.21286b33.chunk.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

when I used Accept: "application/json", I get error 406 response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers

Comment: What is the content-type header in the response?

Comment: Please add more information to your question: proxy configuration, urls you are calling on local and deployed system (as shown in F12 network analysis), authentication scheme on local and deployed system etc.

Comment: There simply isn't enough information here to say why this is happening.

Comment: You should include the proxy configuration and the .NET code where you return a response.

Comment: Sounds like the URL you have constructed to access your API in production is malformed. Can you inspect what URL the response is attempting to access? My guess is that it's a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you are using the wrong url.
It might work using the url of your server instead of the proxy url.